# The more~, the less~

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm learning English in Korea.

I'd like to know if the following sentence is natural.

> The more often you wash your hands, the less you get the possibility of catching a cold.

When I saw that sentence at first, I thought the part with 'the less...' should be corrected like 'the less possibility of catching a cold you get.'

I hope you could give me some guides. Thanks~~

Comment: "... the less likely you are to catch a cold."

Answer (score 4):

The sentence is certainly understandable, but there seems to be a problem with this part:

> the less you **get the possibility**

Words about probability (chance, possibility, likelihood, etc.) can be tricky to use grammatically.

I would reword it like this:

> The more often you wash your hands, the less likely you are to catch a cold.

Another way to word it would be:

> The more often you wash your hands, the lower your likelihood of catching a cold.

As a rule of thumb, use *more* and *less* with adverbs like *often* or *likely*; use *lower* and *greater* with nouns like *likelihood* or *chances*.